# “In an undertone” - an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, parts-of-speech

In this sentence:

> She began to sing, in an undertone, but as she heard the sounds come clear and pure she let herself go.

What is **“in an undertone”**?

I mean, can this whole construction “in an undertone” be an adverb of manner: *She began to sing how? - in an undertone.* Is it some kind of composite adverb, or maybe something else?

Comment: Undertone is a noun. A subdued or muted tone of sound or colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **[prepositional phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositional-phrase/info)** (also known as preposition phrase) because it's headed by a preposition (i.e., *"in"* of *"in an undertone"*).

You can consider it an **[adverbial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial)** or an **adverbial phrase**, functioning as an adverbial of manner (you've identified the "of manner" part correctly).

You can follow the links I included above to find more details about these terms.